# Removing Pictures from PDF using PDFBox - Query on a unworking solution posted here

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I am unable to get the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831194/how-can-i-remove-all-images-drawings-from-a-pdf-file-and-leave-text-only-in-java) to work.

The code runs without any exception and while debugging it show that `resources.getimages().clear();` is doing something, but for some reason the changes are not 'saved' when the output document is created. Rather, the output document is identical to the input.

I have checked that the PDF contains valid images as I've used another code from pdfbox to extract all of them.

Comment: document.save("strippedOfImages.pdf");